# user must login with in entered time interval

Tags: time, authentication, constraints

I have to restrict user login to my application based on the start time( just hour value) and end time(just hour value) they entered. I am storing those values in 1 ... 24 hour format. The query I'm running is.

> select * from table WHERE startHour <= '10' and endHour >= '10'

(10 is current hour). This is not working if user enters end time and start time as 1. Can you guys help me the current way I need to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions. Are the start time and end time only in hours? Also, is it valid if the start time and end time are given the same values? That would mean that the user has to log in at the exact hour inputted and no leeway for minutes past or minutes before. Can you post the structure of your table containing the start time and end time entries?

Also, when you say it's not working, can you give the scenario of what occurs by then? Provide any exact error or issue.

Comment: My table structure is

Comment: @teja, you can update or edit your original question to include the schema/structure of your table, additional details, etc.

Comment: My table structure is just simple storing clientid, start time, end time are integers. Suppose if user entered 1 as start time and 1 as end time. They will have access to login into my app anytime between starttime 1 and endtime 1( basically 24 hours in this case). Currently I'm running above mentioned query startHour(1) <= '10'(currenthour) and endHour(1) >= '10'. Its getting failed.

Comment: So if the user inputs 1 for start time and end time, both would mean "01:00" in 24-hour format? So the only chance the user can log in is at exactly 01:00?

Comment: According to my requirement If they enter same values they must have access 24 hours. If they enter 2 as start time and 1 as end time. They will have access between 2 Am and 1 Am to login into the application.

Comment: Would you be able to change your structure for the table where the start time and end time are stored for each user? You can convert them into datetime formats, where the hour of starttime is the inputted value and the date is the current date. For end time, if it exceeds a value of 23 (which means it's already the next day), you can add 1 DAY for the date. Once you have converted your table into this structure, you can simply use the following query:       SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE starttime<= NOW() AND endtime>=NOW();

Comment: I want this one to be dynamic like if a user gives start time and end time then they must have access between these times everyday.

Comment: Yes, it's dynamic. You may simply have to convert your table into datetime formats so it would be easier to check if the current time is within the starttime and endtime specified.